# Cloudfront disable HTTPS for a certain path

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, https, amazon-cloudfront

I have a cloudfront distribution that redirect http to https properly. However, for a certain path I want the page to be HTTP only. Tried for hours, all the chatbots recommended to use Viewer Request Policy "HTTP Only", a feature that no longer exist.

Used different origins, one for my desired path set as "HTTP and HTTPS" and the second default path "Redirect HTTP to HTTPS". Still getting 307 in the desired path

Comment: If you really want to allow HTTP for a certain behaviour you can try to change `ViewerProtocolPolicy` from `redirect-to-https` to `allow-all` and handle the redirects at the origin.